# How to create an alphabetical index of a word document?

Tags: pdf, word-count

My boss gave me a **pdf** and asked to create an alphabetical index.

The index will contain only interesting (for him) words. The list of 'interesting word' is not available and I'm supposed to create one and show him for approval.

I think I can find a way to transform the **pdf** to **.doc** and Libreoffice can create a alphabetical index once you give it a **.sdi** file containing the 'interesting words'.

So my greater concern now is to extract all unique words from pdf, filter them in order to eliminate the too common ones and create the list of the most significant ones. Any suggestions ? Do I have to write some simple applciation to filter the words or can I use existing software ?

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would extract to doc to get access to text and then use software to analyze and get keywords (or like you put it - interesting words).

TexLexAn is a good open source option:
http://texlexan.sourceforge.net/

Here are others:
http://www.quora.com/What-are-good-tools-to-extract-key-words-and-or-topics-tags-from-a-random-paragraph-of-text

Comment: You're one busy guy.  Take a look at this discussion so you don't get dinged on software recommendations: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Comment: Unfortunately, Bill Gates didn't event a button for Windows called "Press here to extract interesting words from a PDF file". Sometimes, if you're not a programmer yourself, software is the only solution. My advice to you is to focus on user's needs and stop commenting on other's answers and comments.